# Body of POST Request with httpClient got bad syntax

Tags: angular, typescript, request, httpclient

I'm trying to write POST Request with a body. 
Everything works good except the body of my request.
My server receive... :

```
body: { '{"email":"test@test.com","password":"a"}': '' },
```

That's not what I want... I want something like that :

```
body: {"email":"test@test.com","password":"a"},
```

I don't understand what I did wrong... Here is my code.

```
post(url: string, object: any, httpOptions?: {}) {
    return this.http.post<Response>(this.baseUrl + url, object, httpOptions);
}
```

and I use this function here :

```
  let user = new User();
  user.email = this.loginForm.get('email').value;
  user.password = this.loginForm.get('password').value;
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    })
  };
  this.httpService.post('api/authenticate', user, httpOptions).subscribe(result => {
    alert(result.message);
  });
```

Finally, my user class..

```
export class User {
    pk_user: number;
    email: string;
    password: string;
    username: string;
    society: string;
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    locality: string;
    npa: number;
    address: string;
    available: number;
    created_at: string;
    updated_at: string;
}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: What is the variable `object`? Is this a JSON object?

Comment: I edit my post above

Comment: Format okay when you get rid of the httpOptions completely?

Comment: can you console.log object in your post method. To make sure it looks like what you want. Another thing worth trying, instead of doing new User() and assigning the fields, you should be able to just do let user = this.loginForm.value; that'll just give you the json you want

Comment: I got `Object { email: "test@test.com", password: "a" }`, ok thank for advices

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found this solution :

```
post(url: string, object: any, httpOptions?: {}) {
    let httpParams = new HttpParams();
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (key) {
        httpParams = httpParams.append(key, object[key]);
    });
    return this.http.post<Response>(this.baseUrl + url, httpParams, httpOptions);
}
```